# How to make Xcode open a project with a selected file in the editor?

Tags: xcode

Xcode wants to open my current project with the editor on the Main.storyboard file. But that file is corrupted in such a way that Xcode essentially freezes and becomes unusable. Is there a way to make Xcode open the project with the editor on a different file? (The "current file" must be stored somewhere but I can't find where.)

Comment: Try removing xcuserstate from your project.

Comment: Do you know where the xcuserstate file should be? That sounds like a good suggestion but the only xcuserstate files I can find were last modified in 2014.

Comment: Hm, if you right click and "show package contents" of your .xcodeproj or workspace file there should be a du folder somewhere (sorry, I'm not on a computer right now)

Comment: Ok thanks. I found it buried a couple levels down under <proj>.xcodeproj. Deleting it removes all the tabs in my Xcode project and Xcode opens with nothing being edited. I had a tab for each important file in the project and now I have to make them over again but that's fine because now I can get on with using Xcode. I haven't used it enough after that to confirm there are no bad repercussions. If you put that into a separate answer I'll accept it.